# -Perl-How to jump to the next element of a loop if error found?

Tags: perl, error-handling

I just finished a Perl script (which is doing great) with the form:

```
my @plages_IP = ('10.7.10.103' ,'10,121,10,7', '10.120.10.10');

foreach my $IP (@plages_IP)
{
   DO ALL THE THING I WANT;
}
```

My problem is that for some reason, 1 or more IP in my list may be busy at the time i launch the script. In that case, i get some perl error (wich are normal) and the script die:

```
'Error POSTing http://10,121,10,7/wcd/login.cgi: Can't connect to 10,121,10,7:80 (Bad hostname) at C:\Users\STAGEDVIR\Desktop\gnagna\Retrieve_Counter_C364_C224_C203.pl line 51.'

'Error POSTing http://10.64.10.3/wcd/login.cgi: Not Found at C:\Users\STAGEDVIR\Desktop\gnagna\Retrieve_Counter_C203.pl line 45.'
```

I don't want it to die if an error is found but to jump to the next item of the loop ;All those errors mean the same thing (IP currently busy), typically, what i want to do is:

```
if(ANY_ERROR && LOOP_NOT_EMPTY)
{
    DON'T DIE;
    JUMP TO THE NEXT ELEMENT OF THE LOOP;
}
```

I tried some solution with `eval{ routine_might_die }; warn $@ if $@;` and some ways like:

```
unless($boolean_descripting_last_request->is_success)
{
    print(STDERR "Currently busy $IP ! \n");
    **next**;
}
```

But the script keeps dying to the first error he finds due to IP currently busy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're putting the `eval` in the wrong place. If you want to catch errors within your loop, put the `eval` there.

```
my @plages_IP = ('10.7.10.103' ,'10,121,10,7', '10.120.10.10');

foreach my $IP (@plages_IP) {
    eval { 
        # stuff that might die
    };

    warn $@ if $@;
}
```

There's no need for `next` since the loop will continue anyway.

Comment: Awwww yeah. Of course you are right , it's working now. Thanks a lot for the super fast answer, i appreciate it! Have a nice day =)